# How to make complex taxonomy searches

Tags: taxonomy-terms

How do I make complex taxonomy searches? Simplifying my drupal database to the following example (number in quotes are the taxonomy numbers assigned by drupal):

Nodes = Blogs, Stories, Questions, Forums

The following are taxonomy dropboxes

Author = A.Tan(1), B.Chua(2), C.Smith(3), D.Perez(4)
Category = Gadgets(5), Food(6), Movies(7), Entertainment(8)

I want to make a complex search for example all Blogs by B.Chua pertaining only to Movies category? I could almost do this with the advance search since it allows checkboxes to search particular nodes and taxonomy however would not accept a blank or asterix as a search word.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views). Create view for nodes, add a filter for these two vocabularies and expose them, so that they can be selected by the user.

Comment: Thanks Berdir! I tried your suggestion all weekend and it did work well enough for my needs!

Comment: @Dreadstar If this is the answer to your question, then remember to accept it. This site will not go past the beta phase, if users don't accept answers for their questions.